# How to make iOS app be opened from chrome/gmail?

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking

I'm trying to research how to open an iOS app from chrome/gmail. I can only open it through safari/notes.

I read that many years before this was an issue, but as many websites have their apps, and I'm able to open the app from the websites, there must be a way.

I've set the rules in my `info.plist`:

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>myapp</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.myapp.myapp</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

(`myapp` is replaced with my actual app name)

Am I doing something wrong, or there are additional setup to be done?

Comment: Don't use a custom scheme. Use true deep linking (universal links).

Comment: You can use firebase dynamic-links :- https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage